# Measure of a sequence of sets is finite --> nullset

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X, \mathcal A)$ and $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of sets in $\mathcal A$ with $\sum \mu(A_k) < \infty$.

If $A:= \{x \in X: x\in A_k$ for infinitly many $A_k\}$, why does it holds true that $\mu(A) = 0$?

Comment: Another direct proof is to notice that for each positive integer $n$ you have  $$A \subseteq \cup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \implies \mu(A) \leq \mu(\cup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k)$$ and use the union bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)<\infty$ then the restriction of $\mu$ to the collection of measurable subsets of the set $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ can be recognized as a finite measure.

This allows us to apply the [lemma of Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma).

Comment: But without the condition on summability, the original claim is in general not true, is it?

Comment: +1 Since $A=\{x\in X:x\in A_k\text{ for infinitely many }A_k\}=\lim \sup_{k\rightarrow\infty }A_k$ the set $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ should be named differently

Comment: It is enough already if some $m$ exists with $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)<\infty$. If not then it is indeed not true in generality (e.g. take $A_k=A$ for every $k$ where $\mu(A)>0$)